# Is there a way to parse the EMR MasterPublicDNS in Amazon Cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to parse the EMR MasterPublicDNS in Cloudformation? I don't see a replace function in Cloudformation.

`ip-100-112-10-21.aws.internal`

TO

`100.112.10.21`

```
Outputs:
  IPAddress:
    Description: IP address of the EMR clusters
    Value: !GetAtt
      - EMRCluster
      - MasterPublicDNS
```

```
can I reference the output value in same script?
I need to use the formatted IP to set resourcerecords- or do I have to use 
Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
 ResourceRecords: !Join [".",
      [
        !Select [1, !Split ['-', !GetAtt EMRCluster.MasterPublicDNS]],
        !Select [2, !Split ['-', !GetAtt EMRCluster.MasterPublicDNS]],
        !Select [3, !Split ['-', !GetAtt EMRCluster.MasterPublicDNS]],
        !Select [0,
          !Split ['.', !Select [4, !Split ['-', !GetAtt EMRCluster.MasterPublicDNS]]]]
      ]
    ]

 gives error - Value of property ResourceRecords must be of type List of String
 or 
 ResourceRecords: !ref IPAddress.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is always like that, you could combine `Split`, `Select` and `Join` [Cloudformation intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) to achieve it:

```
Outputs:
  IPAddress:
    Description: IP address of the EMR clusters
    Value: !Join ['.',
      [
        !Select: [1, !Split: ['-', !GetAtt EMRCluster.MasterPublicDNS]],
        !Select: [2, !Split: ['-', !GetAtt EMRCluster.MasterPublicDNS]],
        !Select: [3, !Split: ['-', !GetAtt EMRCluster.MasterPublicDNS]],
        !Select: [0,
          !Split: ['.', !Select: [4, !Split: ['-', !GetAtt EMRCluster.MasterPublicDNS]]]]
      ]
    ]
```

I know it makes you cringe, but that's the way to go in Cloudformation.

Alternatively, you could write a [Cloudformation macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to do this for you.

Comment: Thank you - that works well for the output and I am able to get the format I need.

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer so that others can recognize it as helpful too.